# What does setBorderPainted mean?

Tags: java

Very general question, I am just confused on what `setBorderPainted` does. I'm creating a GUI and I need it. What happens if I don't include it in my GUI, will it effect anything?

Thanks

Comment: Did you even *try* to look this up?

Comment: Yes and I got confused, as said, so don't try to belittle

Comment: You demonstrated absolutely *no* effort in trying to solve this.

Comment: You should explain where your point of confusion is, perhaps an instance of where you tried to use it.  Otherwise, the only answer you'll get is "read the manual".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a property of `javax.swing.AbstractButton`.

When you set this property to `true`, and if the button has a border, it will paint the border.

---

*As far as I know in certain OS like MAC, when you set the background color of the button, only the border of the button is painted with color. Some people will set this property to false so that the background can be seen colored.*

Comment: Ah ok, the Mac thing clarified since i'm using one, thanks!